# Why is the Silverlight framerate not showing up in my status bar?

Tags: silverlight, frame-rate

I'm trying to see the framerate of a silverlight application. I'm using IE 8 and have created a new Silverlight app in Visual Studio and simply added a button and set a background color. I've tried it on a more complex app and had no success, so that's why I'm using the most basic of examples.

I've added `<param name="EnableFrameRateCounter" value="true" />` to the object tag, and enabled **Allow status bar updates via script** as documented in the note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838171%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I've tried it with and without debugging. If I enable `EnableGPUAcceleration` I do get the status text from that but it's not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to change the IE security settings as the Note on the MSDN link suggests?

Comment: Yes, I provided the link to show what I have done.

Comment: Ok, just checking... I see that you did say you "get the status text" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the same MSN link says "This property is not settable on instantiation." under the object Syntax header. There is a link to [Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.settings.enableframeratecounter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that shows how to set these settings in code. It would have been nice if they had made that first page more clear.

In your app.xaml.cs in the Startup event, set it in code.

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

(In IE9, I had to show the Status Bar through the View menu > Toolbars)

Comment: So turns out I had the wrong setting in IE security options enabled. Switching on the right one gave me the counter. I tried what you suggested here and it actually works both ways, so I think that part of the documentation might be off. I got the idea about putting it in the object tag itself from these posts: http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/08/15/silverlight-enableframeratecounter-parameter.aspx http://wildermuth.com/2009/02/13/Tuning_Animations_in_Silverlight_Apps

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I learned something today from looking into your question.